# Vector perpendicular to level set of objective function

Tags: convex-optimization

A constant level contour of an objective function 
  $ \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, corresponding to a given value c is the set:
$$ F_c(c)= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x)=c \} $$
Given points $x_0, x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n $
 suppose that the vector $v = x_1-x_0$ is perpendicular to $F_c$ at the point
$x_0$. What does this mean in strict mathematical language ? Does the function $F$ need to be differentiable at $x_0$? How can we prove that gradient whenever exists at $x_0$ is vector perpendicular to $F_c$ at $x_0$ and to points towards increasing values of $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $\frac{df(x)}{x}$ is the gradient. 
 The vectors perpendicular to the gradient are the direction that $f(x) = const.$ 
 Don't know if this helps.